# Trying to use find_peaks

Tags: python, scipy

Hey i'm currently trying to find the peaks in my power spectrum. I have been trying the find_peaks from scripy, but I can't seem to make it work like:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=75mdKyA76i8&t=1363s

Here's my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from scipy.ndimage import gaussian_filter
from scipy.signal import find_peaks
import numpy as np

# Importing data
power_list = pd.read_table(r'G:\Downloads\power_list_6779699.txt')
frequency_list = pd.read_table(r'G:\Downloads\List_Frequency.txt')

# Gaussian filter
df = gaussian_filter(power_list, sigma=37)
List = np.linspace(0, 141699, num = int(141699) , endpoint = True)

for i in range(141699):
    List[i] = df[i]

# Finding peaks
peaks = find_peaks(List, height = None, threshold = None, distance = None, prominence = None, width = None)
height = peaks[1]['peak_heights'] #List of heights
peak_pos = frequency_list[peaks[0]] #List of peak pos
print(peaks)

# Plotting
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.subplots()
plt.title('KIC6779699')
plt.xlim([5.6E1,1.16E2])
plt.xlabel('Frequeny(μHz)')
plt.ylabel('Power density p.p.m')
ax.plot(frequency_list*1E6, df, 'k', linewidth=.2)
ax.scatter(peak_pos, height, 'r', s = 10, marker = 'D', label = 'Maxima')
```

But I get the error
File "C:\Users\Jeffs.spyder-py3\untitled0.py", line 26, in 
height = peaks[1]['peak_heights'] #List of heights

KeyError: 'peak_heights'

Can anybody help?

Comment: try to run until `peaks =..` then  `print(peaks[1])` and `print(peaks[1]).keys()` it's seems that your return object does not have a key named `'peak_heights`. The first print will show you all the properties dict, the seccond one will show you the keys

Comment: okey reading through documentations (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html) it seems that you need to proportionate height in function call to get a peak_heights...

Comment: When I do the print(peaks[1]) and print(peaks[1]).keys() I get the following:


runfile('C:/Users/Jeffs/.spyder-py3/untitled0.py', wdir='C:/Users/Jeffs/.spyder-py3')
{}
{}
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Jeffs\.spyder-py3\untitled0.py", line 30, in <module>
    print(peaks[1]).keys()

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'keys'

Comment: But when I enter peaks in my variable explorer it's a tuple, with two indexes, the array and a dic called {'peak_heights':Numpy array}

Comment: sorry the second one show be `print(peaks[1].keys() ) ` not `print(peaks[1]).keys()`. That's my bad

Comment: Now it gives me

{'peak_heights': array([348.10784763, 139.57301894, ...])}
dict_keys(['peak_heights'])

Comment: so you could call `height = peaks[1]['peak_heights']` now... you are getting the heights well.. let me know if error persists or changes lines

Comment: Running the same code w/o plotting section gives me:
KeyError: "None of [Index(['peak_heights'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"

Comment: wich line? could you please paste the full error trace?

Comment: File "C:\Users\Jeffs\.spyder-py3\untitled0.py", line 30, in <module>
    peak_pos = frequency_list[peaks[1]] #List of peak pos
  File "C:\Program Files\Spyder\pkgs\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3464, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.loc._get_listlike_indexer(key, axis=1)[1]

  File "C:\Program Files\Spyder\pkgs\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1314, in _get_listlike_indexer
    self._validate_read_indexer(keyarr, indexer, axis)
  File "C:\Program Files\Spyder\pkgs\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1374, in _validate_read_indexer
    raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")

Comment: okey the problem is with `frequency_list` it says that's there no key matching with `peaks[1]` that's because it is a dictionary... you maybe want to use `peak_pos = frequency_list[peaks[0]]` ? and maybe you sould use `peak_pos = frequency_list.iloc[peaks[0]]` but you will know better what you're trying to do

Comment: First one did not work peak_pos = frequency_list.iloc[peaks[0]] did.

Comment: When I try to plot I get this error though:
File "C:\Users\Jeffs\.spyder-py3\untitled0.py", line 43, in <module>
    ax.scatter(peak_pos, height, 'r', s = 15, marker = 'D', label = 'Maxima')

  File "C:\Program Files\Spyder\pkgs\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 1361, in inner
    return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)

TypeError: scatter() got multiple values for argument 's'

Comment: I think you can not pass marker color as argument without pointing that is color argument. try:  `ax.scatter(peak_pos, height, c='r', s = 10, marker = 'D', label = 'Maxima')`

Comment: That worked thank you! I think this is the last, do you have any idea why the markers don't show up on the figure?